# Convertir objeto a formato json

Tags: java, json

tengo una duda de como pasar un objeto a formato json, tengo un metodo que hace consulta en la db y me retorna el objeto usuario el VO, que es donde estan los get y los set, cuando recibo esto
// usuario es la clase con los get y set;

```
// Aca me devuelve el objeto con los datos consultados
usuario = usuarioDAO.consultarUsuario(parametro);
```

Mi codigo de volver a formatio json es el siguiente

```
 private String crearMensajeJson(String nombrevar, String dato) {
        JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder().add(nombrevar, dato).build();
        
        return json.toString();
    }
```

El resultado es el siguiente, funciona bien pero tendria que pasar los get de uno en uno ya que asi lo tengo en el metodo de crear el json paso el nombre y la cadena, mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de hacer que el objeto usuario lo pueda convertir de una en json pasando solo el objeto y ya, vi que usan una clase GSON gson = new GSON(); la verdad no se donde encontrar esa libreria y como agregarla

```
{"name":"nombre de la persona"}
```

Comment: Internet... te recomiendo empezar a aprender algo de [tag:maven], te ayudará mucho a futuro

Comment: Qué tiene que ver Maven con la pregunta puntual?

Comment: @Ruslan , creo que tu respuesta no va a lo que pregunte, creo que no todo es maven y si se puede sin maven por que lo echo solo que nose como hacerlo con un objeto, si esas son tus respuestas es mejor que no lo hagas.

Comment: En la parte que dice que no sabe donde encontrar ni como agregar la librería Gson ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, claro. Hay muchas maneras en Java de convertir objetos java en json (y viceversa), dos de las más usadas son Jackson y Gson.
Por ejemplo, en Jackson es tan fácil como :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
usuario = usuarioDAO.consultarUsuario(parametro);
String usuarioJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(usuario);
```

Por supuesto hay muchos detalles que deberás tener en cuenta, si usas fechas, colecciones, grafos de objectos, etc., pero hay muchos tutoriales disponibles en la web, empezando por las páginas de Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson y Gson: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md